# Get the redirected page from Scrapy request

Tags: python, html, url, redirect, scrapy

I'm using FormRequest class from Scrapy to login to a website and scrape its data. However, the problem I'm having is getting the resulting login page. After I submit the form request, I'm redirected to a redirect page, but the page I want is the page that comes after the redirect page. In a regular browser, the redirect page would automatically redirect to the homepage, but in the Scrapy spider, the redirect page is the response and gets trapped there.

How do I get past this redirect page to get the homepage?

Code below:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    start_urls = [
                "https://blahblahblahsecurepage"
            ]

    def parse_evalPage(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("?")[-1].split("&")[0]
        open(filename, "wb").write(response.body)

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        if hxs.select("//form[@id='loginform']"):
            return self.login(response)

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "Please enter a valid username" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return
        # We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
        else:
            return Request(response, callback=self.parse_evalPage)

    def login(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'j_username': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'j_password': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'},
                    formnumber = 1, callback=self.parse_evalPage)]
```

Comment: Does the redirect to homepage come from some Javascript onload() function (window.location = ...) ?

Comment: If the page after the login redirects using either the location header or the meta refresh tag, scrapy will redirect you automatically. Otherwise, as Paul point out, you need to find how the website redirects your request.

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. The website redirects me to a "cannot access" page, which makes me think that there is some form of block against spiders (because I cannot reach that page by entering the wrong username and password).